# PLS-00221: 'DISPLAY_TRANS' is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I am making a PL SQL application for printing a receipt, but I am having a problem with displaying the function. It shows the error --- PLS-00221: 'DISPLAY_TRANS' is not a procedure or is undefined --- when I invoke it.

My function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DISPLAY_TRANS(in_id diamanteruga_invoice.invoice_id%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS 
    v_gas_type diamanteruga_gas.gas_type%TYPE;
    v_gas_liters diamanteruga_gas.gas_liters%TYPE;
    v_gas_priceperliter diamanteruga_gas.gas_priceperliter%TYPE;
    v_gas_amount diamanteruga_gas.gas_amount%TYPE;
    v_vatable_sale diamanteruga_invoice.vatable_sale%TYPE;
    v_vat_exempt_sale diamanteruga_invoice.vat_exempt_sale%TYPE;
    v_vat_zero_rated_sale diamanteruga_invoice.vat_zero_rated_sale%TYPE;
    v_subtotal diamanteruga_invoice.subtotal%TYPE;
    v_vat diamanteruga_invoice.subtotal%TYPE;
    v_amount_due diamanteruga_invoice.amount_due%TYPE;
    v_amount_paid diamanteruga_invoice.amount_paid%TYPE;
    v_change_due diamanteruga_invoice.change_due%TYPE;
    v_payment_type diamanteruga_invoice.payment_type%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    select gas_type, gas_liters, gas_priceperliter, vatable_sale, vat_exempt_sale, vat_zero_rated_sale, subtotal, vat, amount_due, amount_paid, change_due, payment_type
    into v_gas_type, v_gas_liters, v_gas_priceperliter, v_vatable_sale, v_vat_exempt_sale, v_vat_zero_rated_sale, v_subtotal, v_vat, v_amount_due, v_amount_paid, v_change_due, v_payment_type
    from diamanteruga_invoice join diamanteruga_gas using (gas_id)
    where invoice_id = in_id;

    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   DESCRIPTION                                  AMOUNT');
    dbms_output.put_line('________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   ' ||v_gas_type|| '                               '||to_char((v_vatable_sale), '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('       ' || v_gas_liters || ' @ P/L' || v_gas_priceperliter );
    dbms_output.put_line('________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VATable Sale                               ' || to_char(v_vatable_sale, '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VAT-Exempt Sale                              ' || to_char(v_vat_exempt_sale, '0.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VAT-Zero Rated Sale                          ' || to_char(v_vat_zero_rated_sale, '0.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   Sub Total(12% VAT)                         ' || to_char((v_vatable_sale/1.12),'9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VAT(12%)                                   ' || to_char((v_vatable_sale-(v_vatable_sale/1.12)), '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   Amount Due                                 ' || to_char(v_amount_due, '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   Cash Tendered                              ' || to_char(v_amount_paid, '9999.99'));

    if (v_amount_due-v_amount_paid) <= 0 then dbms_output.put_line ('   Change Due                                   ' || to_char((v_amount_due-v_amount_paid),'0.99'));
    else dbms_output.put_line ('   Change Due                                   ' || to_char((v_amount_due-v_amount_paid),'9999.99'));
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   PAYMENT TYPE: ' || v_payment_type);
    RETURN NULL;
    END DISPLAY_TRANS;
```

And my invoker looks like this:

```
    set serveroutput on
    BEGIN
    DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170);
    END;
```

Output is supposed to be:

```
  DESCRIPTION                                  AMOUNT
________________________________________________________________
   8 PREMIUM 95                                 500.00
       11.99 @ P/L41.7
________________________________________________________________
   VATable Sale                                 500.00
   VAT-Exempt Sale                               0.00
   VAT-Zero Rated Sale                           0.00
   Sub Total(12% VAT)                           446.43
   VAT(12%)                                      53.57

   Amount Due                                   500.00
   Cash Tendered                                500.00
   Change Due                                    0.00

________________________________________________________________

   PAYMENT TYPE: Cash
```

Please help me find a solution...

Comment: You create it as a function, like so you have to attrib some value to it. something like `declare somevar number; begin somevar:=DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170); end;`

Comment: Drop the function. Create or replace **procedure** ...

Answer (score 2):

You execute a PL/SQL Function in wrong way.
The correct ways are:

1) Since a function returns a value we can assign it to a variable.

```
declare result varchar2(20);
result :=  DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170);
```

2) As a part of a SELECT statement

```
SELECT  DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170) FROM dual;
```

3) In a PL/SQL Statements like,

```
dbms_output.put_line( DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170));
```

This line displays the value returned by the function.

However in your case, better option is procedure. Drop the function (`DROP FUNCTION DISPLAY_TRANS`) that you created and try the below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure DISPLAY_TRANS(
in_id diamanteruga_invoice.invoice_id%TYPE
) 
 AS 
    v_gas_type diamanteruga_gas.gas_type%TYPE;
    v_gas_liters diamanteruga_gas.gas_liters%TYPE;
    v_gas_priceperliter diamanteruga_gas.gas_priceperliter%TYPE;
    v_gas_amount diamanteruga_gas.gas_amount%TYPE;
    v_vatable_sale diamanteruga_invoice.vatable_sale%TYPE;
    v_vat_exempt_sale diamanteruga_invoice.vat_exempt_sale%TYPE;
    v_vat_zero_rated_sale diamanteruga_invoice.vat_zero_rated_sale%TYPE;
    v_subtotal diamanteruga_invoice.subtotal%TYPE;
    v_vat diamanteruga_invoice.subtotal%TYPE;
    v_amount_due diamanteruga_invoice.amount_due%TYPE;
    v_amount_paid diamanteruga_invoice.amount_paid%TYPE;
    v_change_due diamanteruga_invoice.change_due%TYPE;
    v_payment_type diamanteruga_invoice.payment_type%TYPE;
 BEGIN
    select gas_type, gas_liters, gas_priceperliter, vatable_sale, vat_exempt_sale, vat_zero_rated_sale, subtotal, vat, amount_due, amount_paid, change_due, payment_type
    into v_gas_type, v_gas_liters, v_gas_priceperliter, v_vatable_sale, v_vat_exempt_sale, v_vat_zero_rated_sale, v_subtotal, v_vat, v_amount_due, v_amount_paid, v_change_due, v_payment_type
    from diamanteruga_invoice join diamanteruga_gas using (gas_id)
    where invoice_id = in_id;

    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   DESCRIPTION                                  AMOUNT');
    dbms_output.put_line('________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   ' ||v_gas_type|| '                               '||to_char((v_vatable_sale), '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('       ' || v_gas_liters || ' @ P/L' || v_gas_priceperliter );
    dbms_output.put_line('________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VATable Sale                               ' || to_char(v_vatable_sale, '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VAT-Exempt Sale                              ' || to_char(v_vat_exempt_sale, '0.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VAT-Zero Rated Sale                          ' || to_char(v_vat_zero_rated_sale, '0.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   Sub Total(12% VAT)                         ' || to_char((v_vatable_sale/1.12),'9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   VAT(12%)                                   ' || to_char((v_vatable_sale-(v_vatable_sale/1.12)), '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   Amount Due                                 ' || to_char(v_amount_due, '9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('   Cash Tendered                              ' || to_char(v_amount_paid, '9999.99'));

    if (v_amount_due-v_amount_paid) <= 0 then dbms_output.put_line ('   Change Due                                   ' || to_char((v_amount_due-v_amount_paid),'0.99'));
    else dbms_output.put_line ('   Change Due                                   ' || to_char((v_amount_due-v_amount_paid),'9999.99'));
    end if; 
    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line ('');
    dbms_output.put_line ('   PAYMENT TYPE: ' || v_payment_type);

 END DISPLAY_TRANS;
```

The procedure can be called declivity by:

```
SQL> EXECUTE  DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170);
```

Or like you mentioned:

```
BEGIN
DISPLAY_TRANS(000000322170);
END;
```